# How to get the average of a column that contains a string with a number?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that contains a column with a list of names and column for a list of levels. The level column has a data type of string. I am trying to get the average for the levels for my list of people. So the table below should populate the average level which is Level 2.8 ((2+4+2+2+4+3)/6)-> and I want it to show the integer below the average level - thus: 'Level 2' should be the result.

How can I add the levels since these are strings and not numbers?

TABLE A

| Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Joey | Level 2 |
| Rachel | Level 4 |
| Ross | Level 2 |
| Pheobe | Level 2 |
| Monica | Level 4 |
| Chandler | Level 3 |

RESULT:
Level 2

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Why does column 2 contain the word at all? If you name your column `Level`, and make it an integer, you don't have this problem. Make all columns  you need to perform math operations on the appropriate data type in the first place.

Comment: I know, but that's how the table is. I can't change the this column. Is there anyway I can still calculate the average level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be different depend on which dbms you are using :

```
SELECT  AVG(CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(column2, 'level ', '') as INTEGER))
FROM TABLE
```

or as it mentioned in the comment you can use `oreplace':

```
SELECT  AVG(CAST(OREPLACE(column2, 'level ', '') as INTEGER))
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your answer. I'm getting a syntax error though. Does this replace 'Level' with the number inside? I am using Teradata

Comment: which database sytem are you using ? i

Comment: I'm using Teradata

Comment: It worked!! Oh my goodness, thank you sooo much!! :)

Comment: Teradata supports `oReplace`, should be more efficient than a RegEx.